# Babel Plugin: How to insert a sibling node

Tags: javascript, plugins, babeljs, babel-plugin, babel-babylon

It seems that path.insertAfter(), path.insertBefore(), path.unshiftContainer(), and path.pushContainer() only work with Statements. How do you insert nodes that are not Statements?

In my case I am writing a babel jsx plugin and I am trying to insert a sibling node which is a JSXExpressionContainer. When I do this I get the following error:

`TypeError: Property body[0] of BlockStatement expected node to be of a type ["Statement"] but instead got "JSXExpressionContainer"`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation [here](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#toc-inserting-a-sibling-node):

```
FunctionDeclaration(path) {
  path.insertBefore(t.expressionStatement(t.stringLiteral("Because I'm easy come, easy go.")));
  path.insertAfter(t.expressionStatement(t.stringLiteral("A little high, little low.")));
}
```

---

Looking at your error, make sure you do your types correctly. Just check babel types [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-types#jsxattribute) and see what parameters are needed by each type.

Comment: This doesnt work. It gives the same error as in the question. I am using babel7

Comment: I think this is an error with the types you're trying to insert, not the `.insertBefore()` or `.insertAfter()` functions. Just try to insert something simpler. I have a babel project, and I've used `.insertAfter()` with a node and it works. @SouradeepNanda

Comment: I am trying to insert JSX.

Comment: Very very late. But I guess you just need to look at the link in the post. I gave it a quick look. Maybe this is what you're looking for `t.jsxAttribute(name, value);`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by just pushing the code as plaintext. React seems to work just fine.

```
path.node.children.push('<div>Click me</div>')
```